# RabbitMQ 3.5 and Message Priority Queue process is waiting until the task completion

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have some priority based tasks in my application.  I have two queues "queue1" and "queue2", i want to gave highest priority to queue1 and lowest priority to queue2. I setup  queue1 priority number is 255 and queue2 priority number is 200.  I am having an issue in executing the tasks , once priority task is taken , The process is waiting until the task completion synchronously. But as per our project need, this process shouldn't be waiting but just kick off it. How do I achieve it?

I refereed [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue/blob/3431dc1ef8ea53e9a556c6be8bc1b417ac03b58d/examples/java/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/PriorityQueue.java) blog,

Message Received part:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    ch.basicConsume(QUEUE, true, new DefaultConsumer(ch) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Received " + new String(body));
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    latch.await();
```

I already done this process without priority queue in RabbitMQ https://pamlesleylu.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/hello-world-for-spring-amqp-and-rabbitmq/

Producer

```
  public void execute() {
    System.out.println("execute...");
    messageQueue.convertAndSend("hello " + counter.incrementAndGet());
}
```

Consumer

```
 public void onMessage(Message msg) {  
    System.out.println(new String(msg.getBody()));  
    try {  
        Thread.sleep(1000);  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hand the task off to another thread (e.g. using a `TaskExecutor`).

Bear in mind, though, that the message will be acked so if the server crashes you will lose that message.

It would probably be better to increase the `concurrency` in the listener container so you can handle multiple messages at once.